# Search using php code

Tags: php

I've successfully written a search engine in PHP,

After testing it, there's one thing that bothers me.

First error

```
(mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in)
```

Second error

```
(mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in)
```

Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query...

here's the code

```
<?php

echo "<h2>Search Results:</h2><p>";

//If they did not enter a search term we give them an error
if ($find == "Account_Number")
{
echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term!!!";
exit;
}

// Otherwise we connect to our Database
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

// We perform a bit of filtering
$find = strtoupper($find);
$find = strip_tags($find);
$find = trim ($find);

//Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM memaccounts WHERE upper($field) LIKE'%$find%'");

//And we display the results
while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
echo $result['Account_Number'];
echo $result['Name'];
echo "<br>";
echo $result['Balance'];
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
}

$anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data);
if ($anymatches == 0)
{
echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query...<br><br>";
}

//And we remind them what they searched for
echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$find;
//}
?>
```

please help, Thank you

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: your query if failing.

Comment: How have you 'successfully' written a search engine if your first query fails?

Comment: to properly filtering the input, use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. By the way, if your table collate is case insensitive, you do not need to change it to upper case

Comment: $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM memaccounts WHERE upper($field) LIKE upper('%$find%')");

Comment: you have not define any $field variable....

Comment: You also haven't initialized `$find`.

Comment: Which php version are you running? are you using `register_globals`? Or you processed `$_GET` or `$_POST` before?. Also, follow ShivanRaptor advice or you are wide open to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Here's my previous code 
    
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM memaccounts WHERE upper($field) LIKE'%$find%'");

then I changed it 

    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM memaccounts WHERE Account_Number LIKE'%$find%'");

when i search an account number it worked but it just display all my account in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `$find` and `$field` are not defined, the query becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM memaccounts WHERE upper() LIKE'%%'
```

which makes `mysql_query()` return `FALSE` , as it is an incorrect query. (i.e. `$data` is `FALSE`). Therefore, `mysql_fetch_array()` and `mysql_num_rows()` fails with error as `FALSE` is supplied as input.

Hints:

- to properly filtering the input, use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. By the way, if your table collate is case insensitive, you do not need to change it to upper case.
- You can always debug your codes by `var_dump()` , `var_export()`, `echo` or `print_r()` (depends on situation)
- stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.
- your code is subjected to SQL Injection attack, as you directly allow POST values to be inserted in your query.

Comment: where should I defined it?

Comment: You of course have to give values to `$find` and `$field` in order to use them in query.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query() returns false if there was a SQL error. You have to check if $data is false before looping through results. An example to to this:

```
if (!$data) exit(mysql_error());
```

or just add "or die(mysql_error())" at end of mysql_query() line in same way as you did with connect and select_db.

Comment: +1 for checking results, but this answer doesn't say why the query fails in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely there is an error on your query. Check that there isn't any typo on it.
I'd recommend to capture the query (echo it or log it) and then run it using any database client like phpmyadmin or heidisql.

Answer (score 0):

The query will probably work, except when `$find` contains invalid characters. For instance, if it contains a quote (`'`) then it will break your query.

You can use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to solve this, although it's probably better to quit using the mysql* functions at all and switch to PDO. The mysql* functions are deprecated and will probably be removed in a future version of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Please check the query.
mysql_query() this function returns true or false to show query worked or not.
your result shows boolean means query failed.
use mysql_error() 
for ex :- 
$result=mysql_query('Your query');
if(!$res){
 die(mysql_error()); //gives information regarding error
}
```

Comment: please format your answer. `var_dump('select query ');` is not a valid syntax.